# Cant connect remote PervasiveDB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net, pervasive

I am developing ASP.NET MVC application that interacts with PervasiveDB, running on separate external database server. I use Pervasive ADO.NET Data Provider with connection string like: `ServerDSN=dbname;UID=user;PWD=password;ServerName=87.xxx.xx.xxx;`
On my development machine everything is fine while debugging with IIS express, but when i deploy my app on remote hosting server that runs IIS 7.0 i am getting exception, when trying connect db.

Code:

```
PsqlConnection conn = new PsqlConnection(ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
try
{
  PsqlCommand cmd = new PsqlCommand(query);
  cmd.Connection = conn;
  PsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  while (reader.Read())
  {
    ...
  }
}
finally
{
  conn.Close();
}
```

Exception:

`2013-01-28 15:40:21.2574|ERROR|App.WebApiApplication|Pervasive.Data.SqlClient.PsqlException: A  connection   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 87.xxx.xx.xxx:1583   at Pervasive.Data.SqlClient.PsqlConnection.Open()
   at App.DBFacade.TestConnection()
   at App.WebApiApplication.Application_Start()`

Ping from hosting server to database server is OK.

I don't realize what's the difference between my development enviroment and production one, and how can i fix this error.

Comment: Even if you can ping the DB server, maybe the port is blocked by a firewall. Look at the firewall logs to find it's the traffic it's being blocked. Also double check you are using the correct credentials.

Comment: I use same remote database with same connection string when running app locally and it works fine, the error is only on hosting server.

Comment: Make sure the firewall on the hosting server isn't blocking port 1583.  Also, make sure the engine itself is running when the error occurs.  The error you are seeing is only returned when the provider can't communicate with the server.

Comment: Thanks for advices, they helped me to solve problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this error was that hosting provider blocked connection on given ip and port.